# Insert Character on batch folder rename

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator

I have a folder that has several hundreds of thousands of files named like "ABC 123456". I need to add a dash after between the two blocks of text like this "ABC - 123456". Leaving the trailing space.

Automator does not offer a method for counting 4 characters in and inserting an new dash and space.

I have this terminal command and have been tinkering with it.

```
for file in *.txt
do
  echo mv "$file" **"$file" count 3 "- "**
done
```

Anyone know of an Applescript or can help with the terminal command that will help me rename the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question itself isn't exact too, because the OP talks about:

- files names like `ABC 123456` (without extension), but in the example code using `*.txt` extension
- *add a dash between two blocks* (e.g. where is the space) like `ABC - 123456`, but in the next taking about `counting to 4` and `count 3`, e.g. not exacltly clear what the script should do for example if find `ABCD 12` or `AB 345`
- also, want keep the trailing space, what is strange - but OK ;)

The problem is dividable to 3 separate parts:

1. selecting the right files for the rename
2. preparing the new filename, replacing/adding characters into the old one
3. the "physical" rename

Ad "selecting the right files". Selecting the files, can be done by some external utilities, for example by the `find` command.
The main benefits of the `find` are:

- it can search files recursively in the sub directories too
- is possible more precisely select the right files, e.g. exclude directories, select files by time or size and so on. (check from the terminal `man find`.)

Ad "prepare the new name". This can be done by external programs,
like `sed` or `awk` or any program what can manipulate text in shell
scripts, *or* it can be done (in some simple cases such this) withing
the `bash` itself - and is possible to save one expensive command execution.
(for hunderts of thousand files it makes a difference).

The following:

```
${file/ /-}
```

substitutes (replaces) one *space* (the `/ /` part) with the *dash* (`/-`). So it is possible to write

```
mv "$file" "${file/ /-}"
```

and save the `sed` execution.

**So one of the alternative solutions could be**, for example the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename
do
    newfilename="${filename/ /-}"
    [[ "$filename" != "$newfilename" ]] && echo mv -i "$filename" "$newfilename"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "* *.jpg" -print0)
```

The abobe is for the *DRY RUN* - it only will show, what will be done, for the real execution remove the `echo`.

Decomposition:

- selecting the right files for the rename: the `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "* *.jpg" -print0` will find all

  - what are only in the current directory (`-maxdepth 1`)
  - and they're *plain files* (`-type f`)
  - and their name matches *(anything)(space)(anything).jpg* case insensitively - e.g. the name must contains a space
  - supply the filenames as *null terminated*, so their name can safely contain newline character too. (`-print0`)
- the cycle `while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename; do ... done < <( )`

  - reads the output from the above `find` command
  - where the filenames are *null terminated* (`-d $'\0'`)
  - ignore any escaped characters (`-r`) /advanced topic - not needed to explained here/
  - the `IFS=`  prevents trimming of leading and trailing whitespace from the filename (also, a bit advanced topic)
- preparing the new filename `newfilename="${filename/ /-}"`

  - is done by `bash` internally (without executing an external command).
  - if want preserve the trailing space after the dash use `${filename/ /- }`
- the actual renaming is done by the `mv` command (see `man mv` from the terminal), where

  - the `-i` what will ask the user if here are already a file with the new filename (don't override it)
- and the `mv` is executed only when the `newfilename` is different from the `filename` `[[ "$filename" != "$newfilename" ]]`

The above solution is mostly error-prone, but it still isn't very effective,
because for hundreds of thousand files will execute hundreds of
thousand times the `mv` command.
The solution can be: using some
utility, what can read the filenames and do the renaming without
executing the `mv` command N-times.
For example, the "big gun" of system admins the "perl", as:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0 |\
    perl -0nle '$n=$_; $n=~s/ /-/; rename $_,$n unless($_ eq $n || -e $n)'
```

what will rename all files what outputs the `find` in one execution - e.g. much faster as thousands of `mv` executions.

Tor testing (DRY RUN) use the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0 |\
    perl -0nle '$n=$_; $n=~s/ /-/; print qq{old:$_ new:$n\n} unless($_ eq $n || -e $n)' #print instead of the rename
```

Ps: the perl is powerful enough to handle everything itself, eg. the find command too, but it is more advanced topic...

Ps2: my English is much worse as my `bash`, so someone could kindly edit this post for adding/correcting things.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

If your file names are "ABC 123456" with single space between the first 3 and the following, then you are trying to replace the space with a character (or dash or something), so to look like ABC-123456.

I found [this article](http://www.chrislongcreativeservices.com/replacing-spaces-in-file-names-on-osx/) that explains how to do that.

Example:

Note that the following command will only replace spaces with hyphens. If you need a different substitution you’ll have to modify the command accordingly

```
for i in *.JPG; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed -e 's, ,-,g'`"; done
```

Others:

If you wanted underscores or any other character instead of a hyphen, you’d simply switch the `s, ,-,g` part of the above command to `s, ,_,g`.

For how to [see this article](http://www.chrislongcreativeservices.com/replacing-spaces-in-file-names-on-osx/).

Here is a **Test** on my MBA 10.9.5 (I used a ABC 123456.png file) and placed it in a new folder. Than I did the cd to that directory in Terminal and run

```
for i in *.png; do mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed -e 's, ,-,g'`"; done
```

Result is, it works great (it renames the file)

How does it work:, it would replace the space in file name on all *.png files in that folder, so make sure to have it on the right folder first.

[image: renamed]